# How long will an app continue to run on my iOS device if installed via Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Just started to play around with iOS and built a very simple app which I use and test on my iPad. If I click "stop" in Xcode the app can still be launched and used on my iPad without Xcode debugging.

Considering I don't have an Apple Developer Account and probably won't buy one until I get up and running, how long will the app I "run" on my phone continue to function without having to connect it to Xcode and re-"run" the compilation process again?

Comment: As long as you have the device.

Comment: @DanielStorm Sorry but that's not correct. Please see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There is no dev-related provisioning scheme that is permanent.
>
> - Free provisioning (no paid developer account) is good for 7 days.
> - TestFlight distribution (via Xcode and a purchased developer account)
>   is good for 90 days.
> - Local/ad-hoc installs (via Xcode and a purchased developer account),
>   to a device registered in the Member Center, are good for max one
>   year, but no longer than the time left on the dev's annual paid
>   account.
>
> Apps
> via the store are re-signed by Apple and never expire.

Source: [Apple developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/91519), posted by user [KMT](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/profile/KMT).

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the app will not *survive* backup restores and iOS major version upgrades (not 100% sure about that one).

Apart from that the app will continue running. That is really nice if you want to make just a simple app for your own, you can just put it on your phone and use it, no need for a paid dev account or anything.

Comment: Or a personalised app that the kids / grand children can show off at school and that nobody else has.

Comment: This is definitely incorrect in 2023. Was it ever correct?

Answer (score -4):

You app can run forever without the need to recompile it and re-install via Xcode, just like an app downloaded from the Store.

Comment: How can i do that without break jail?